# HTML Text suddenly change font after using non-breaking hyphen code

Tags: html, css, pdf, thymeleaf

I am generating a pdf document with HTML using thymeleaf. In one of the pages, I tried to use a non-breaking hyphen (‑) on my text but when I use it, the text after the code suddenly changes font. But this only happens on CentOS server, it works fine on my local machine.

I have tried using the default system Arial font, and I have also tried installing the default Arial font from my machine on the server but the same thing happens.

The code is very simple:

```
      // CSS
      html,
      body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 8pt;
        max-width: 210mm;
        width: 210mm;
        height: 297mm;
      }


      //HTML
      .....
      .....

      <li>
            Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
            accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa
            quaeillo&#8209;quaeillo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto
            beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
            voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur
            magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro
            quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur,
            adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut
            labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad
            minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit
            laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur
      </li>
```

Here are the outcome from my machine and the server:

Local Machine:

[image: Output from local machine]

Server:

[image: Output from CentOS server]

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Could you create a runnable snippet and make sure it does show the problem.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example